# how to recover windows 7 overwritten by ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, data-recovery

I installed ubuntu server 18.04 on my computer, and there was an error when setting up the partition, so the windows 7 hard drive and my data were deleted / overwritten by this ubuntu install, I've tried the boot-repair method, an error like this appears
`Unable to init server: cloud not connect`
and `xhost: unable to open display`

and I try to see in the grub menu there is no my windows os, in the bios boot settings it is also the default.

can you help me solve this problem, to be able to recover my data right?

Comment: Ask Ubuntu isn't the correct place to ask about Windows installation issues since it is off topic but this would be on topic on Super User. However, this is a good opportunity to replace Windows 7 since it has been EOL for quite some time now. This means that it has widely known and published security flaws that will never be fixed.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood my question and statement, here I installed ubuntu instead of installing windows

Comment: I suggest you to read my post Questions carefully

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu on an SSD or on a spinning disk hard drive? If you installed on an SSD, there is zero chance of recovering the data. If you installed on a spinning disk, then there is a small chance that you can recover files, depending on how you performed your installation.

Comment: now you understand it, for the location of the SSD or Hard drive I forgot at that time what I chose when partitioning.
if there is a solution to restore via ubuntu can you give a little command

Comment: If Windows was overwritten by Ubuntu it is not recoverable. We cannot assist with Windows problems or Windows (re) installations

Comment: That's great for the current answer, really helpful.